# Clear the exam - is there any difference from 'pass the exam'

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, vocabulary, frequency

I've just came across the collocation 'clear the exam'.

Even though I do understand the meaning from the context, I could not find this phrase in Longman dictionary, 
and when googled the search results are mostly shown for 'pass the exam'.

[image]

I was just wondering about the frequency of usage, etc.

Comment: That's a link to a question on Quora; what makes you think the asker is a native English speaker?

Comment: If you want to do google search for a phrase, use quotation marks `"clear the exam"` . For the frequency, you can use google [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=clear+the+exam%2C+pass+the+exam&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpass%20the%20exam%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @DanielRoseman Quora question was just the result of my googling :)  Originally I've faced that phrase while preparing to the certification exam. Here's a link to it http://istqbtests.net/test2.php?student=sdfd&question_type=ISTQB%20Foundation&start=112

Comment: I was texted just last night by a neighbor from India “thank you for sharing your wifi today. I was able to take the test without any issues (although I didn’t clear it).” This, and an earlier comment lead me to believe that this usage is common in India.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Clear exams* or *clear an exam* seems to be a common expression in Indian English.

I've never encountered it in US English; but it doesn't appear at all foreign or quaint. We use *clear* in racing (horse and human) to speak of successfully leaping over a fence or hurdle, and *clear the hurdles* is often extended figuratively to other sorts of obstacle, such as legal and regulatory requirements.

In about three hours I'll be calling my wife, who is to turn in the last of three doctoral comps at noon. If she says "Well, I've cleared **that** at last!" I'll know exactly what she means.

Comment: I know some incompetent English leaners in Malaysia use that phrase because it's a direct translation of *"selesai peperiksaan"* in my native language.

Comment: @user178049 It's perfectly competent English--it's just not the usual English. But that's how the language grows.

Comment: I've taught in Canada and lived in Texas and never heard the expression. I understood it immediately, however.

Comment: As on-line education becomes more ubiquitous, a new meaning is emerging: _"My browser locked up before I was through taking the test. Can you **clear the exam** so I can complete it?"_ (In that case, though, _clear the exam_ is really just a shortened version of _clear the exam **attempt**_.)

Comment: @J.R. I think though that that is a distinct sense of *clear*, as in "clear the decks" or "clear the table". OP's *clear* effects a new position of the subject; your *clear* effects a new state of the object.

Comment: Not British English either. It sounds odd to my ears and it is not immediately obvious what it means.